# unable to assign values to variables in python

Tags: python

I am trying to pull datastore values from vcenter and perform usage calculations as below:

```
s = VIServer()
s.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD)


properties = [  "name",
                "summary.capacity",
                "summary.freeSpace",
             ]

results = s._retrieve_properties_traversal(property_names=properties,
                                           obj_type=MORTypes.Datastore)
d = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for item in results:
    for r in item.PropSet:
                if r.Name == "name" :
                        name = r.Val

    for p in item.PropSet:
        global Total_Space,Free_Space
        if p.Name=="summary.capacity":
                Total_Space=p.Val
                Metric="datastore.space_total"
                print Metric,d,p.Val,"datastore="+name,"source="+"datastore"

        if p.Name=="summary.freeSpace":
                Free_Space=p.Val
                Metric="datastore.space_free"
                print Metric,d,p.Val,"datastore="+name,"source="+"datastore"
        if Total_Space>0 &  Free_Space>0:
                Used_Space=Total_Space-Free_Space
                Used_Percent=(Used_Space/Total_Space)*100

                Metric="datastore.space_used"
                print Metric,d,Used_Space,"datastore="+name,"source="+"datastore"
                Metric="datastore.diskPctUsed"
                print Metric,d,Used_Percent,"datastore="+name,"source="+"datastore"
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datastore.py", line 41, in <module>
    if Total_Space>0 &  Free_Space>0:
NameError: global name 'Total_Space' is not defined
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem: You should change the `&` to `and`.  `&` does something entirely different.

Comment: Looks like you could get to line 41 without ever assigning a value to Total_Space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code logic it makes sense to check these values after **for** loop. Thus, you will make sure that they are initialized and checked once:

```
 ...
 Total_Space = 0
 Free_Space = 0
 for p in item.PropSet:
     ...

 if Total_Space and Free_Space:
     ...
```

However, if you'd initialize them to None, you can have additional check for presence them in **PropSet** :

```
 ...
 Total_Space = None
 Free_Space = None
 for p in item.PropSet:
     ...

 if Total_Space == None:
     print "error: no Total_Space in PropSet"
 elif Free_Space == None:
     print "error: no Free_Space in PropSet"
 elif Total_Space and Free_Space:
     ...
```

**Some notes:**

- You should use **and** boolean operator instead of **&** for bitwise operator
- Moreover, **&** has [higher priority](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm) than **>** and expression will be evaluated as

  if Total_Space > (0 & Free_Space) > 0:
- In conditionals, you can use just *if value* instead of *if value>0*

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am getting space_total, space_free but not used_space and used_percent, it looks like the last if statment is not processing.

Comment: @user1471980 but do you see these properties when you reading p.Val? Just to make sure you really receive/read these property values as zeroes?

Comment: I do see the values as here:datastore.space_total 2014-11-25 17:41:04 2684354560000 datastore=NFS13 source=datastore
datastore.space_free 2014-11-25 17:41:04 1781300174848 datastore=NFS13 source=datastore

Comment: @user1471980 "if Total_Space and Free_Space:" should work (not &)

Answer (score 1):

initialize `Total_Space` and `Free_Space` with a value in first of your program.

```
Total_Space = 0
Free_Space = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not declare `'Total_Space'` globally before say `global Total_Space`, your should add `Total_Space = None # or whatever value you like` globally, i.e. outside of for loop or any function